# Supervisor wants ownership of an Overleaf project I created

Tags: authorship, supervision

A student approached me with some ideas he had been working on in computer science and asked if I could study the result and then write it up into article format as he dislikes writing and that it would never get written if I did not do it.

As a result I am a co-author along with the student and his supervisor.  I wrote the article up using an Overleaf project and then invited both the student and supervisor to join the project on Overleaf.  It seems like the student did not tell the supervisor about this choice he had made, as I spoke to his supervisor and he seemed a bit surprised.  He said ''that's cool'', but he can be very hard to read, saying one thing and meaning something very different.

The student's supervisor has now messaged me being asked to be made owner of the Overleaf project.  Is there any possibility of trickery going on here.  Could he be trying to substantially change the writing of the document and then remove me as a co-author?  I appreciate that I did not contribute ideas but I did put a lot of effort into writing.  The student explicitly asked me for help with writing and said I could be a co-author as it would not get written otherwise without my intervention.

Overleaf warns me that this action cannot be un-done and that the new owner could remove my access to the project.  Is it possible that he is trying anything devious as he thinks I should not be a co-author?  I am wondering if the supervisor feels that he should have been asked about this first and as a result thinks that I should not be a co-author on the paper.

Comment: We can't predict the actions and intent of another. Sorry. It could be benign. It could be terrible. You need to judge. Perhaps the three of you need to come to some agreement that works for all.

Comment: What is your relationship with the student??

Comment: We work in the same lab on some of the same projects and are on good terms.

Comment: Beyond writing, what is your intellectual contribution to this project?

Comment: I only contributed to the writing, I did not contribute new ideas: I just wrote the paper up.  So I may just have to transfer ownership  and accept what happens, I think I should have asked the supervisor on his opinion of this before writing it up.  It didn't take long to write, so would not be a huge loss.

Comment: You certainly don't own the content of the project. You may not even have a claim on authorship itself if you didn't contribute ideas. You are, in effect a ghost writer.

Comment: "Is there any possibility of trickery going on here?" -- how can any random person on the internet know, if you can't?

Comment: @Buffy I have checked the manuscript again and I realised that I did actually contribute something to the mathematical interpretation of their results.  I think I didn't realise as I thought it was obvious, but it seemed like they didn't know this until I wrote it down.

Comment: Unfortunately, Scott and Buffy are right: you might be considered only a write-up help. I suggest ask for a 3-way meeting where the facts are put on the table to clarify what your status is: co-author? At the minimum, acknowledgement, although it sounds a bit low-balling your contribution to readability. I think you need to negotiate. If you do not get co-authorship, this is a take-away lesson to clarify your authorship status earlier on. If you do not get even an acknowledgement, express your disappointment, and just detach yourself and concentrate on your other stuff.

Comment: If you, as you added, indeed have a contribution, you should get co-authorship, no question. Not first author, not last author, but co-authorship.

Comment: In practice, it would very hard to write up an academic article without making some sort of intellectual contribution. The process of writing up ideas usually plays a crucial role in refining the ideas and making their formulation more precise, highlighting any short-coming or pitfalls.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ownership of the Overleaf project doesn't actually mean much. It wouldn't take more than 2 minutes for the supervisor to create a fresh Overleaf project, and copy over the existing content from the current one anyway. Conversely, you can make a local copy of everything yourself before signing it over, and you'd be in a pretty similar situation when it comes to fighting for authorship.

Answer (score -6):

I would not be surprised if he immediately deletes the project to destroy any proof of your contribution when you transfer ownership. He won't enter into any dialogue then regarding the project.  In the future you might get some sort of narration of the situation from him that his student never promised you anything and you were just a write up assistant like an LLM.

I would personally tell him an error has occurred when attempting to switch the ownership of the project. I would warmly tell the supervisor that he may send changes to you that he needs to make to the document and you will update the document for him and you are happy to continue contributing to the project, paper etc.

You will avoid stepping into open confrontation and you retain proof of your publishing of the document first.  From there he will be forced to show his hand to you and justify his requests.

By doing this you will force him to rewrite the entire paper himself if he wishes to exclude your name as coauthor of the paper.

If the student made an honest mistake and from the supervisors perspective you can't or do not deserve to be a co-author , you should then accept you are not a co-author **if he rewrites the paper from scratch.**

However I suspect it will be difficult without major similarities occurring (You got there first before he did, his loss your gain) or too much effort for the supervisor to rewrite the paper without including what you contributed. It will be too risky to include anything you did while this proof exists.

It will be safer and less effort for them to include your name as long as you retain ownership of the original project on overleaf. So you have all this leverage on them. Don't be a nice guy or a fool, don't help them screw you over. This project is proof of your contribution , if you do not hand it over he will respect you more I think and be cautious of the consequences of removing you as co-author.

Comment: I don't think this answer is helpful at all. It engages in speculation about supervisor's intentions and the paragraph suggesting to lie about some error that occured makes no sense, as you do not need ownership of the project to make changes. Apart from that, this is not how a collaboration should work among scientist that OP makes changes on the document on behalf of others.

Comment: OP asked us explicitly to speculate on the the intentions of the supervisor. He presented evidence for us to make our judgement. If the supervisor asks for ownership and if ownership is not required to make changes it is reasonable to assume one of the possibilities is that he wishes to delete the project. I pointed out possibilities that were likely to not be considered previously by OP instead of iterating over the obvious ones you and others would probably think of.